# Recieving NotFoundError when downloading unnamed files from a Node.js server

Tags: node.js, express

I'm downloading files from a Node.js server in Debian using the following code:

```
var publicPath = __dirname + '/public';

app.get('/public/*', function (req, res) {
    var file = publicPath + req.path;
    res.sendFile(decodeURI(file));
}
```

Files download successfully unless they're unnamed. Downloading '/public/.txt' or '/public/.exe', for instance, doesn't work (named equivalents do). The following error is given:

```
NotFoundError: Not Found
    at SendStream.error (/home/user/server/node_modules/send/index.js:270:31)
    at SendStream.pipe (/home/user/server/node_modules/send/index.js:585:14)
    at sendfile (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1099:8)
    at ServerResponse.sendFile (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:429:3)
    at /home/user/server/server.js:279:6
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at param (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
    at param (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
    at Function.process_params (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
    at next (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at expressInit (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at query (/home/user/server/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5)
```

Is there any way to download these files without naming them?

Comment: How would you want to send a file that does not exist on your server?

Comment: Also, it's not clear if you want to send a file, or a file to download in client. Then you would use `res.download`?

Comment: These files do exist on my server within its public directory, '/home/user/server/public/', and I've tried both res.download and res.sendFile without success. Both return NotFoundError and are capable, as far as I'm aware, of downloading files to a client.

Comment: Obviously, if the file does not exist, how do you want to send it?

Comment: Both, `res.download` AND `res.sendFile` require for the file to exist on the server. Otherwise, they cannot do anything.

Comment: The files do exist.

Comment: Oho, I will write an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to explicitly allow `dotfiles` In order for it to work (with a older version of `Express`:

> app.use(express.static( __dirname+'/public', {dotfiles:'allow'} ));